# Label placement on slanted nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to slant a node with a label, however, the label gets misplaced.

Am I using the label/slant facilities incorrectly or is this a bug?

[image: label misplacement]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw,label=Test,anchor=south west] {abc};

    {[every node/.append style={xslant=.5},xslant=.5]
            \node [draw,label={[red]Test},anchor=south west,red] {abc};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct since labels are also nodes the transformation is applied twice.

You can limit the transformation with `every label` style key and let the nodes acquire the current transformation via `transform shape` key.

Note that this quite limited and you have to keep the transformation order in mind hence it won't fix every node/label property clash.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw,label=Test,anchor=south west] {abc};

\begin{scope}[every label/.append style={xslant=0},xslant=.5,transform shape]
     \node [draw,label={[red]Test},anchor=south west,red] {abc};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]